Density matrices and locality
I'm having trouble understanding the physical aspect of entangled sub-systems, suppose I have a global entangled state:
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle_{A} \otimes |1\rangle_{B} + |1\rangle_{A} \otimes |0\rangle_{B}\right)
\end{equation}
The sub-system that $A$ measures is obtained by partial trace, and thus corresponds to a classical statistical mixture:
\begin{equation}
\rho = \frac{1}{2}\left(|0\rangle\langle 0| + |1\rangle\langle 1|\right)
\end{equation}
If I understand correctly, this means that the state measured by $A$ is in one definite, but unknown state, and the same is true for $B$. Since both states are definite, but unknown, each of them corresponds to a classical random state, but then how can their correlation violate Bell's inequalities in the first place?
If $A$ and $B$ are just revealing the respective unknown state of each particle, then by Bell's theorem I expect their correlation to be restricted, yet in quantum mechanics a stronger form of correlation is created, which violates the bound, does this mean that the description in terms of density matrices of $A$ and $B$ is not correct?

There are two notions of "mixed", as e.g. described in d’Espagnat's book. The state of subsystem $A$ cannot be pure, and so the corresponding reduced density matrix cannot be interpreted as a classical probability distribution which describes a lack of knowledge, while there is a "true" (pure) state which is unknown or so.

I don't understand this, what is the "true" pure state which is unknown? Pure states have a density of rank 1, which is different from the density in this case, right?

My language was, perhaps, bad. The important thing I noted is that you are asking about the difference of proper vs. improper mixtures. One admits an ingorance interpretation, and one does not.

Oh, ok I never heard of proper vs improper, how can Bob tell that his mixture is improper or proper in this case?

I don't have enough time to write an answer (sadly, because I think this is a very good question). I pointed out a reference; if you search with Google the key words you should find many more. What I want to answer does not fit into a comment.

A better way to word your final question would be:  “Does this mean that the description in terms of subsystem-density matrices of A and B is not complete?”.  The answer to that question is “Yes.”
Consider a generic 100-qubit system.  Here the full density matrix is a $2^{100}$ x $2^{100}$ matrix, containing all the known information about that state.  That’s a lot of information.
But the subsystem/reduced density matrix of each qubit, generated by taking partial traces, is just a set of 100 2x2 matrices.  Clearly there can’t possibly be as much information in these 400 numbers as there was in the full state.
What’s missing from this reduced description is exactly what you’re asking about – the correlations.  The reduced description tells you (correctly) what you might be likely to measure at any given qubit, but it can’t tell you the expected correlations.  To find that information you need to recover some of that information you’ve thrown away in the reduction process.
And, therefore, you can’t deduce anything about Bell-inequality-violations (or the corresponding nonlocality or retrocausality implied by those violations) from the reduced density matrices alone.

Thanks, I revisited this answer but I am still not convinced of this argument, doesn't QM predict that the actual state of the sub-system is mixed? My problem was that in this case, it's impossible to interpret this mixed density as classical ignorance about the sub-system, yet this is normally done whenever a mixed density appears in QM, it seems like we are forced into having two notions of mixed density?

You are steering towards a much more interesting question here!  Every state of classical ignorance does indeed correspond to a mixed density matrix.  Does that mean that every mixed density matrix, even on a subsystem, corresponds to classical ignorance?  Most people would say 'no', but I think it's more subtle; it depends what exactly one means by "classical ignorance".  And I don't think you can answer this question without talking about ontology (what is actually going on) and epistemology (what we have knowledge about).  Those are famously "scrambled" together in conventional QM.

So basically, there is no consesus or answser to this?

Because to me, scrambled just means that we really don't understand what's going on

“[Quantum mechanics] is not purely epistemological; it is a peculiar mixture describing in part realities of Nature, in part incomplete human information about Nature, all scrambled up by Heisenberg and Bohr into an omelette that nobody has seen how to unscramble. Yet we think that the unscrambling is a prerequisite for any further advance in basic physical theory. For, if we cannot separate the subjective and objective aspects of the formalism, we cannot know what we are talking about; it is just that simple.” — E. T. Jaynes
